# Composer not installing requires with dev-master stability

Tags: php, composer-php, requires

I have three projects:

Main project with site:

```
{
    "name": "vendor/example.com",
    "type": "project",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "vendor/constructor": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

Constructor library

```
{
    "name": "vendor/constructor",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "type": "library",
    "require": {
        "vendor/framework": "dev-master@dev"
    }
}
```

Framework library

```
{
    "name": "vendor/framework",
    "type": "library",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "zendframework/zendframework": ">=2.3"
    }
}
```

When I run `composer install` in framework everithink is ok, when I run it in constructor everithing is also good. But if I run `composer install` in project with site I have error:

```
  Problem 1
- vendor/constructor dev-master requires vendor/framework dev-master@dev -> no matching package found.
- vendor/constructor dev-master requires vendor/framework dev-master@dev -> no matching package found.
- Installation request for vendor/constructor dev-master -> satisfiable by vendor/constructor[dev-master].
```

So how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe you just need to specify the [version in each library](https://getcomposer.org/doc/02-libraries.md#specifying-the-version)?

Comment: Libraries doesn't have version, they are in development at this moment.

Comment: I want to install current master of this packages.